# Etymology: of unknown origin

Tags: etymology

Does anybody know how many words in the OED have the remark "of unknown origin"?. I read it often, but have no idea how to find an answer. I guess one would have to ask the editorial staff of the OED.

Comment: If, as I believe is the case, the OED is available online, I would search (Ctrl + f) *"of unknown origin"* in inverted commas, and the computer should say how many instances there are.

Comment: A full text search returns 849 entries containing 'unknown origin' and 843 containing 'of unknown origin'.

Comment: A search of the etymology sections returns 815 for OUO and 822 for UO.

Comment: @JEL That's a surprise, I would have thought more. What's the first and last one? If I can take the liberty of asking.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 'Aal' is the first and 'zythum' the last for UO in Etymology.

Comment: Just googling around I found this post by Exapno Mapcase  in the thread English words with unknown etymologies. The post is too long for a comment, so I give the beginning and the link.  Those in love with vocabulary and etymology will want to read Treasure-House of the Language: The Living OED, by Charlotte Brewer. It's a bit dry in spots, well, arid, but overall it's a tremendously interesting look backstage at the making of the OED and its supplements.

Comment: Brewer has sifted through the extensive archive of memos from a century to get at the arguments, debates, prejudices, and fiats of the lexicographers who put the OED together. She demonstrates that thousands of words have faulty histories or poor definitions ...    http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=482881   It is post no. 18

Comment: Of course, we also need to have an idea where OED is only presenting probabilities with formulations like "probably, perhaps" and the like. I don't consider those cases where the semantic logic is obviously  in question.

Comment: @JEL I suggest a new idiom for "completely mysterious": "unknown from aal to zythum."

Comment: @deadrat, I'll adopt that idiom. Also, if you ever need to get the last word in, or need to pronounce on what "get the last word in" means, "Zythum!" and its meaning will serve: "In ancient Egypt: a kind of malt beer. // Much of the word's continuing use is due to its status as the last word listed in several dictionaries ...." [OED](http://oed.com/).

Comment: @JEL Excellent!  A round of zythum for everyone at the bar.  And see what the stiffs in the back room of the pyramid are having.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the 1981 study by Sterling Eisiminger, [“Etymology Unknown: Toward a Master List of Words of Obscure Origin”](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455025), and his 1984 followup, [“Etymology Unknown: The Crème de la Crème de la Crème”](https://www.jstor.org/stable/455000).

The author of the study wrote to Merriam Company and found that according to their dictionary there are **538** words of unknown origin. The author further goes on to cross check this list with a dozen other dictionaries (including Oxford English Dictionary) to narrow it down to **84** words that are of near mysterious origins. To quote,

> They (*the 84 words*) are the crème de la crème of English etymological mysteries.

The papers were published in 1980s. The first paper contains the full list of the said 84 words and the motive of the author was to spur etymological research in those obscure words.

Comment: Evidently, the 454 words that the author removed from consideration are words that at least one respectable dictionary has offered an etymology for but that MW considers unpersuasive and not yet settled. Presumably, a significantly larger number of words exist for which different authorities have proposed different etymologies but for which MW feels confident that its etymology is correct. One example is "OK," whose etymology past MW dictionaries have treated in multiple ways, but which MW now seems quite convinced comes from "abbr. of _oll korrect_, facetious alter. of _all correct_."

Answer (score 1):

Quite literally, there are 910 entries in the OED that contain "of unknown origin". You can see this by searching ["of unknown origin"](http://www.oed.com./search?f_0=Etymology&pageSize=20&q_0=of+unknown+origin&scope=ENTRY&type=dictionarysearch) in the online OED. If you expand the search to also include results that contain ["unknown origin"](http://www.oed.com/search?case-insensitive=true&f_0=Full+Text&f_1=Full+Text&nearDistance=1&o_1=OR&ordered=false&q_0=origin+unknown&q_1=unknown+origin&scope=ENTRY), there are 2207 entries.

Many of these entries have not been updated. Also, for most of these entries, there is *something* known about the etymology. For example, the page for *aal* (the first result) says it's from:

> Hindi āl Indian mulberry tree, of unknown origin